# gitlab-ci.yml extending another yml file with artifact

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I want to add a file to our artifacts to trace an artifact to the pipeline ect, but when I extend a yml the artifacts section is ignored

test.yml:

```yaml
.artifact_tagging:
  before_script:
    - 'echo "Commit hash: $CI_COMMIT_SHA" > .pipeline'
    - 'echo "Pipeline number: $CI_PIPELINE_IID" >> .pipeline'
    - 'echo "Job name: $CI_JOB_NAME" >> .pipeline'
    - 'echo "Job ID: $CI_JOB_ID" >> .pipeline'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - '.pipeline'
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
job:
  extends: .artifact_tagging
  script:
    - echo work
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME"
    paths:
      - 'project/bin/Release/**/publish/**'
    expire_in: 2 days
```

the .pipeline file is never added as an artifact. It works find if I include .pipeline in the .gitlab-ci.yml just not when it is included.

Comment: This is expected: you are overriding the `paths` attribute, NOT appending. You could use the `reference` syntax, or a variable with list of paths (overriden in the extending job).